# Value error while running linear regression graph

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas

I know there are a lot of questions about this problem but I tried all the answers and they didn't work for me. The ValueError is in the line that I want to plot and scatter the graph. Where is my mistake?

edit: here is excel file https://github.com/b2200356049/Dataset

```
data = pd.read_excel('dataset.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
x1=df[['NOC','CBO','RFC','LOC','CLOC','FanIn','FanOut','LCOM','WMC','DIT']]
y1=df[['TD']]

x2=df[['NOB', 'V','SH','CS']]
y2=df[['CDR']]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(x1,y1,test_size=0.30,random_state=53)


regressor=LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(x_train,y_train)


mae=mean_absolute_error(y_test,y_pred)
mse=mean_squared_error(y_test,y_pred)
rmse=np.sqrt(mse)

plt.scatter(x_test, y_test, color = "red")
plt.plot(x_train, regressor.predict(x_train), color = "green")
plt.title("Test Graph")
plt.xlabel("x axis")
plt.ylabel("y axis")
plt.show()
```

When I ran the code I got the ValueError: x and y must be the same size.

Here is the Traceback error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-bba14b9ba78f> in <module>
     85 rmse=np.sqrt(mse)
     86 
---> 87 plt.scatter(x_test, y_test, color = "red")
     88 plt.plot(x_train, regressor.predict(x_train), color = "green")
     89 plt.title("Test Graph")
ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

Comment: If you post your actual data instead of a picture, and post the entire traceback error it will help you get an answer faster.

Comment: I know but i couldn't add the data :(

Comment: Copy and paste it from excel

Comment: Great!  Now paste the entire error message you get at the end of your question :)

Comment: I added that too.

Comment: You are missing your imports at the top of the code, please make it so we can copy/paste and run it.  y_pred is not defined in the code you posted.

Comment: y-pred are not necessary you can remove it. That part is about other part of my code.

Comment: You're supposed to make the code a [example] (in this case, you need to remove unnecessary parts of the code, make sure it's runnable, include some mock data)

Comment: Besides -- for debugging, try printing out the length of `x_test` and `y_test` to see if they're the same; and read the documentation carefully to see how `scatter` should be used with dataframe with multiple columns.